# Give group the right to send kill signals

Tags: kill, group, signals, privileges

I have a process that a user1 runs. And I need to grant all the group members the right to send some `kill` signal to it. So far, I always get this output:

```
myProcess(13919): Operation not permitted  
myProcess: no process killed
```

From what I had found on the internet, Linux architecture is intended to not allow other users to send `kill` signals to a process. But, if I am ok with it, can I grant these rights?

**Update**

As pointed out by **muru**, I should mention that my group and I are not sudoers.

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/137207/how-to-kill-a-process-started-with-a-different-user-without-being-root-or-sudoer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is limiting damage. You can get quite close with `sudo`. Consider this `sudoers` entry:

```
%group1 ALL = (user1) pkill -HUP <name of process>
```

Then members of `group1` can do:

```
sudo -u user1 pkill -HUP <name of process>
```

Comment: maybe your solution works. But not for me, because I am not a sudoer, I am just a regular user, like all my group.

Comment: @amine perhaps you should mention your constraints in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no permission structure for processes like there is for files. Thus you need tricks like sudo or a SUID / FSCAP binary.